# Implementing deeplinking with multiple levels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement deeplinking for my site as it's built heavily in AJAX. I understand the basic idea and have got deeplinking implemented for my top level nav. Problem is my site has multiple levels. A user can click on the top nav, which adds to the hash and then click on a secondary nav and a tertiary nav. I also need to add this secondary and tertiary nav click in to the hash...and then also be able to remove that item when the user clicks back on a primary nav item. I can't think of a way to do this...any ideas?

Oh and the code (jQuery) I'm using to achieve the hashing on the primary nav is:

```
updateHash : function(hash) {
    var hashHistory = [];
    location.hash = hash;
}
```

Comment: Anybody? Is the question unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I' not quite sure what you are looking for. Maybe you should show some concrete examples. Until then how about something like this:

```
function updateHash(hashPath) {
   if (hashPath.charAt(0) == "/") {
     location.hash = "#" + hashPath;
     return;
   }

   var currentHash = location.hash.split(/\//);
   if (currentHash[0]) currentHash[0] = currentHash[0].substr(1); // Loose the #

   var relHash = hashPath.split(/\//);

   var part;
   while (part = relHash.shift()) {
     if (part == "..") {
        currentHash.pop();
     } else {
        currentHash.push(part);
     }
   }

   if (currentHash.length > 0)
      location.hash = "#" + currentHash.join("/");
   else
      location.hash = "";
}
```

Examples:

```
updateHash("/topLevelItem");
alert(location.href); // "www.example.com/#/topLevelItem"

updateHash("secondLevelItem");
alert(location.href); // "www.example.com/#/topLevelItem/secondLevelItem"

updateHash("thirdLevelItem");
alert(location.href); // "www.example.com/#/topLevelItem/secondLevelItem/thirdLevelItem"

updateHash("../differentThirdLevelItem");
alert(location.href); // "www.example.com/#/topLevelItem/secondLevelItem/differentThirdLevelItem"

updateHash("../../differentSecondLevelItem");
alert(location.href); // "www.example.com/#/topLevelItem/differentSecondLevelItem"

updateHash("../anotherSecondLevelItem/anotherThirdLevelItem");
alert(location.href); // "www.example.com/#/topLevelItem/anotherSecondLevelItem/anotherThirdLevelItem"

updateHash("..");
alert(location.href); // "www.example.com/#/topLevelItem/anotherSecondLevelItem"
```

Comment: That code looks really promising, thanks! I'm a confused though. If a user has clicked on a second level item and i've used the updateHash function to add the hash, how do i then know that if the user clicks on another second level link that i need to send ../differentsecondlevellink as opposed to /secondlevellink to the updateHash function the next time round? Do i keep a track of which level the user is on and then do some logic that does something like if the user is on the second level and they're clicking a second level link then append ../ before the argument sent to updateHash?

Comment: It's ok...I've managed to get it all working now. Many thanks for your post...it really helped me!